# How to pass data from ag grid to typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I want to pass ag grid data (without selection) to type script on button click , how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have asked two separate questions.

In answer to the title of your question, "Is there any event in ag grid to detect onload data", yes, it's `rowDataChanged`.

In answer to the body of your question, which I assume means "how can I set the grid's row data?", use the `setRowData` method of the grid's api.